# Unable to load env files from custom path in Serverless framework

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am unable to load env files located in a custom path using serverless framework.

The env files are kept in a folder 'config/environment' in the project and the files available are

- .env
- .env.dev
- .env.qa
- .env.prod

The contents of Serverless.yml are as below

```
plugins:
   - serverless-dotenv-plugin
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, "dev"}
  dotenv:
    basePath: ./config/environment/
    logging: false
```

While triggering 'serverless deploy', I get error as below

> Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
>
> - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.xxxxxx": Value not found at "env" source,
> - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.xxxxxx": Value not found at "env" source,
> - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.xxxxxx": Value not found at "env" source,
> - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.xxxxxx": Value not found at "env" source,
> - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.xxxxxx": Value not found at "env" source,

It seems the .env files are not getting loaded and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `path` instead of `basePath`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
The problem happend when I update serverless framework v3 from v2.
If I don't use basePath or path and move .env, .env.prod to root folder it works, but I hope to have better solution.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-plugin/issues/52#issuecomment-664970150)

```
dotenv: {
  path: 'config/${self:provider.stage}/.env',
},
```